# What is the advantage of using Intent() instead of finish() when going back to the previous page?

Tags: java, android

My professor has showed us that the way to go back to the previous activity is to create a new activity. But I noticed that this adds the a new activity onto the stack creating multiples of the activity. When I asked him about it he could not give a clear answer and I was wondering what is the main advantage of creating a new activity and increasing the size of the application stack instead of using finish() just to return to the main activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//more code
 }
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_products) {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, ProductsActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }
}//this is how we move from main activity to the products activity
```

ProductsActivityCode:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_home) {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

As you can see we create a new activity in both directions when going to the products activity and coming back to the MainActivity()

Comment: The answer depends on what you intent flags the activity was actually started with. You can force only one activity in the stack, or you can launch a brand new one with fresh state and hope the old one properly destroyed, but if it isn't there ought to be ways to prevent users from backing into a bad activity state

Comment: The old activity is never destroyed, when using a back button of the phone it starts to go through all the activities that were created. An example is if I have a MainActivity() and move to a different Activity called AboutUsActivity() and go back multiple times, when I use the back button I go through all of the acitivities as many times as I moved through the pages.

Comment: I can't speak for your professor's answer, but maintaining the back stack is described here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: "I was wondering what is the main advantage of creating a new activity and increasing the size of the application stack instead of using finish() just to return to the main activity?" -- on the whole, your instincts appear to be correct, and it is unclear why your instructor is teaching you this way.

Comment: Reading external state is not what I was referring to. I'm talking about more minute things - you've scrolled half way down the activity, a checkbox remains clicked, etc. But yes, like I said, the answer depends on what state you'd want, however he's still wrong in his response because you can use Activity lifecycle methods to save, clean, and restore state whether or not a new Intent was made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My professor has showed us that the way to go back to the previous activity is to create a new activity.

Well, that's wrong because "the way to go back to the previous activity" is to do nothing in code and press the back button since that's default Android behavior.

> But I noticed that this adds the a new activity onto the stack creating multiples of the activity.

That is the expected behavior based on the code you posted, yes.

> When I asked him about it he could not give a clear answer

Obviously we don't have the full context and just your comment, but if your professor teaching you Android development can't explain how navigating between Activities in Android works, you might want to find a new professor ...

> I was wondering what is the main advantage of creating a new activity and increasing the size of the application stack instead of using finish() just to return to the main activity?

There is no advantage and in fact has several disadvantages, as you noted. This is not the way "to go back" in Android.